# Declaring variable inside a class and assigning value dynamically

Tags: php

Can somebody help me regarding this :

```
class Helper_common
{
    public static $this_week_start_date = date**(**"Y-m-d", strtotime( "previous monday"));
}
```

When I define variable inside the class it gives error on the start bracket of date function.

Comment: BTW, next time please post the exact error message rather than a brief description of it ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Free PHP code is not allowed outside class methods, you can only write constant expressions.

In a regular property, you could simply do it from the from the constructor or some other method:

```
class Helper_common
{
    public $this_week_start_date;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->this_week_start_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime( "previous monday"));
    }
}
```

But you have a static property. I can't think of any other solution, apart from doing it from outside the class:

```
class Helper_common
{
    public static $this_week_start_date;
}
Helper_common::$this_week_start_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime( "previous monday"));
```

It's probably better to rethink your design.